# Split string on first occurrence of number or comma

Tags: f#

I am a C# developer interested in learning F#. I have a quite simple problem: to split a string into two parts on the first occurence of a number or comma. Obviously, the naive implementation would be:

```
let parts = text.Split([| ','; '0'; '1'; '2'; '3'; '4'; '5'; '6'; '7'; '8'; '9' |], 2)
```

However, this does not look very functional and has probably a terrible performance. I wonder, is there a better way to do this in F#? I was looking at [Active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns#parameterized-active-patterns), but could not figure out how to use them properly. Or should I use the "good old" Regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing un-functional about using standard .NET library operations if they are not mutating. The `Split` operation takes a string and returns a collection of strings, so it is perfectly functional.

One issue with your code is that `Split` will split the string into multiple parts than just 2 if there are multiple numbers or spaces in the string, so you may want to use `IndexOf` to find the index of the first splitting character and then used that to split the string.

I would not bother with using anything sophisticated like active patterns and regular expressions in this case. The following is pretty clear:

```
let splitString (s:string) =
  let i = s.IndexOfAny("0123456789 ,".ToCharArray())
  if i < 0 then None 
  else Some(s.Substring(0, i), s.Substring(i+1))
```

It would be worth using active patterns if this was a part of a more complex rules processing system where you have 10+ such rules that you need to encode, but for a single function, simplicity is the best!

Comment: Aside from the fact that your answer is really informative, I'd like to say special thanks for the little trick with `.ToCharArray`. It is one of those snippets of code that change programmers life forever :)

Comment: @Storm Thanks for a nice comment! The `ToCharArray` trick just shows how lazy I am :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ToCharArray` method to get the char array of the string, then use the `Array.tryFindIndex` function to find the separator, and finally use the `Substring` method to split the string into two parts.

The code would be like this:

```
let str = "hello,world"
str.ToCharArray ()
|> Array.tryFindIndex (fun ch -> ch = ',' || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
|> function | Some i -> str.Substring(0, i), str.Substring(i + 1)
            | None -> str, ""
```

---

I don't really know why you actually want to use Active Patterns here. However, the use of Active Patterns might be useful when you have multiple ways to separate the string. It can help the code more readable, for example:

```
// Write some Active Patterns:

let split condition (str: string) =
    str.ToCharArray ()
    |> Array.tryFindIndex condition
    |> Option.map (fun i -> str.Substring(0, i), str.Substring(i + 1))

let (| SeparatedByCommaOrDigits | _ |) str =
    str |> split (fun ch -> ch = ',' || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
    
let (| SeparatedByDotOrUnderscrore | _ |) str =
    str |> split (fun ch -> ch = '.' || ch = '_')

// The beauty of Active Patterns:

let str = "hel,lo_world"
match str with
| SeparatedByCommaOrDigits (a, b) -> printfn "%s\n%s" a b
| SeparatedByDotOrUnderscrore (a, b) -> printfn "%s\n%s" a b
| _ -> printfn "invalid"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "good old" Regular Expressions for this:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let parts text =
    let a = Regex.Split(text,"[,0-9](.+)")
    if a.Length < 2 then None else Some (a.[0],a.[1])
```